Finding the spectrum of operator $Ax(t)=\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos (t+2s)x(s)\, ds$ in $L_2[0,\pi]$
The problem I'm solving asks to find the spectrum of the integral operator $Ax(t)=\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos (t+2s)x(s)\, ds$ in the space $L_2[0,\pi]$, which is the space of all function from $[0,\pi]$ to $\mathbb{C}$, such that the square of their absolute value is integrable on $[0,\pi]$ in the Lebesgue sense, with the scalar product defined as $(f,g)=\int_{0}^{\pi} f(t)\overline{g(t)}\, dt$. I was wondering whether my solution was correct. In particular I am concerned about my differentiation trick.
As it is known, this operator is compact. Therefore, $0\in \sigma (A)$. And if $\lambda\in \sigma (A)$ and $\lambda \neq 0$, then $\lambda\in \sigma _p (A)$, meaning it's an eigenvalue.
Assume that such a $\lambda$ exists. Then there exists $x\neq 0$, such that $\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos (t+2s)x(s)\, ds=\lambda x(t)$.
Let $\phi(s,t)=\cos (t+2s)x(s)$. Notice the following three points. $\phi(s,t)$ is integrable on $[0,\pi]$ when $t$ is fixed. $\phi(s,t)\in C^1 [0,\pi]$ when $s$ is fixed. $|\phi_t'(s,t)|\leq |x(s)| \in L_1[0,\pi]$. These three facts imply that we can differentiate our integral with respect to the parameter.
After differentiating we get the following $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos (t+2s)x(s)\, ds=-\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin (t+2s)x(s)\, ds$. Similarly, we can differentiate one more time and obtain the following $-\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos (t+2s)x(s)\, ds=-\lambda x(t)=\lambda x''(t)$. Which implies $x(t)=C_1 \cos (t) + C_2 \sin(t)$. It is not hard to see that $Ax(t)=0=\lambda x(t)$, which implies that $x(t)=0$. And we arrive at a contradiction. Thus, $\sigma(A)={0}$.
Is this solution correct?
